# Swift String Memory Leak

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Instruments tells me that I have some "minor" memory leak when manipulating strings in my iOS 9+ application (Swift 2.2).

Here an example :

```
var htmlString = "Blah"
htmlString += "Bleh"
htmlString = "<div class=\"wrapper\">" + htmlString + "</div>"
```

Is it because I'm using the htmlString instance to redefine this same instance? What would be the good way to do this, is it using two variables?

Comment: This code does not leak memory.

Comment: Are you running instruments on the simulator? I've seen [spurious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spurious) leaks reported on the simulator in past SDK versions.

Comment: by default swift doesn't easily leak memory. this code certainly doesn't. that  said, consider that it could be a swift language bug. use swift 3

Comment: I don't know about leaks in this example, but it's usually more efficient to use inline substitution instead of string concatenation, e.g. `var htmlString = "<div class=\"wrapper\">\(your-value-here)</div>"`.

Comment: I've heard stuff about concatenating `String`s with the `+` operator. It slows the compiling time down, so maybe it also leaks memory... But I really, really don't think so.

Comment: I'm running on my iPhone 6s. It really shows memory leak on this line but I wasn't really taking care of it. As you said, it doesn't seems to be a memory leak indeed. Just wanted to make sure!

Comment: I don't think this code would cause any leak. You might be disguided because the instrument might be pointing this part of code to you and tells you that this causes a leak, but actually it's really not. I have a similar experience before then I came to realize that the instrument only points "a part of the program flow" that causes the leak. In your cause, this part of code may just belong to the couple of executions that causes the leak, but not really this part.